# Tools to cleanup a mySQL database that is already normalized?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-cleaning

I have a MySQL database, which I need to cleanup the data in.

I am looking to see if there are tools to help clean the normalized tables at one time.

Example:

- `User` table includes codes for `make` and `model`
- `Make` table has makes that I would like to consolidate
- `Model` table has models that I would like to consolidate

Doing this manually is a nightmare:

1. Change references in `model` table (example delete redundant models
   "B" and "C", leaving model "A"
2. Now all `users` referencing `models` "B" or "C" need to be manually
   changed to reference `model` "A"

Changing a `make` is even more difficult, since all `models` will have to be moved to the remaining `make`, `user` tables updates, etc.

Are there are tools out there to make this simple, perhaps something graphical?

Comment: If your user table includes codes for make and model then your database is not normalized.  That sounds like a many to many relationship to me.  In any event, there are probably no tools to deal with your specific situation, because you might be the only person in that situation.  Stand by for an answer proving me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `Make` and `Model` each have an ID and a description, and there are several `Make` and `Model` records with either identical or equivalent descriptions which you would like to consolidate.

If the descriptions are identical, you could write an Update statement to set the foreign key column equal to the first ID of the primary key column based on a join on the description.

If the descriptions are not identical, you could create a table with two columns, containing in the first column the ID you want to assign, and in the second, the ID(s) you want to reassign, then write an update query similar to above.